# How can I bind to the IsSelected property of a DataGridRow in a sort-safe manner?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, sorting, datagrid

As part of a project I am working on, I need to bind to the IsSelected property of a DataGridRow. We use this binding in our ViewModel to determine how to display data (which varies depending on how many items are selected). Additionally, we use the use the IsSelected value to manually select values on the Grid without having to have our ViewModel know about the DataGrid itself.

For the most part we have this working just fine (see the simplified example). The problem is when we start using the default DataGrid sorting.  At this point the 2-way binding causes us to get some rather unexpected results.  To see this behavior:

1. Run the sample code provided
2. Click on 'John', this will cause the 'Selected' checkbox on the row to become selected
3. Click on the 'Name' header to sort.
4. Click on 'David' to change the selection and checkbox to David's row.
5. Click on the 'Name' header to sort again.
6. At this point you can see that we now, inexplicably, have 2 rows selected and checked (John and David).

As you can see the binding works just fine as long as you don't sort, and then it just goes haywire.  I need a way to bind the IsSelected property without the unexpected behavior after sorting. Please note: I understand that I can get most of what I need by changing the binding Mode to OneWayToSource, but I really do need the 2 way binding.

Thank you in advance for your help!

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="DataGridTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid Name="UIDataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True">
            <DataGrid.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
                    <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected}"></Setter>
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.Resources>
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Selected" Binding="{Binding Path=IsSelected}"></DataGridCheckBoxColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code Behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows;

namespace DataGridTest
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {

        public ObservableCollection<Selectable> Selectables { get; set; }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Selectables = new ObservableCollection<Selectable>();
            Selectables.Add(new Selectable {Name = "Adam", IsSelected = false});
            Selectables.Add(new Selectable {Name = "John", IsSelected = false});
            Selectables.Add(new Selectable {Name = "David", IsSelected = false});

            UIDataGrid.ItemsSource = Selectables;
        }
    }

    public class Selectable : PropertyChangedNotifier
    {
        private bool _isSelected;
        public bool IsSelected
        {
            get{ return _isSelected; }
            set
            {
                _isSelected = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("IsSelected");
            }
        }

        private string _name;
        public string Name
        {
            get { return _name; }
            set
            {
                _name = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Name");
            }
        }
    }

    [Serializable]
    public abstract class PropertyChangedNotifier : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        [field: NonSerialized]
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the selection mode to single on the DataTable. When I did this with your example code it worked the way you intended it to.

```
 <DataGrid Name="UIDataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" SelectionMode="Single" IsReadOnly="True">
```

Comment: thanks for the help here. Setting the SelectionMode to Single would indeed prevent the extra rows from being selected. It would not, however, actually resolve my problem. As part of the project my users need to be able to select multiple rows. The number of rows selected is critical to determining how to display the data (see above).

Comment: Ok I understand... So you would need to be able to select multiple rows but only have one checkbox checked at a time?

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't explain this very well.  The problem is not with the checkboxes, but with the selection itself.  As I select and then sort the items, I expect that I should always have the same selection AFTER the sort as I had BEFORE the sort. The sort itself should not change the selection (whether or not it is bound to anything). So in my steps above, everything is fine in until step 5. Here I start with David selected, but when the sort is completed I have both David AND John selected.  This addition selection during the sort is what I am trying to prevent.

Comment: Any idea how to get this behavior?

Comment: I'm sorry I haven't had time to look at it again. Today i will